# Exporting DataTable to Excel remove line breaks

Tags: c#, .net, excel

Hi I am using the code below to export a datatable to an excel file

```
string attachment = "attachment; filename=Data.xls";
Response.ClearContent();
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";

string tab = "";
foreach (DataColumn dc in dtDataForExport.Columns)
{
    Response.Write(tab + dc.ColumnName);
    tab = "\t";
}
Response.Write("\n");
int i;

foreach (DataRow dr in dtDataForExport.Rows)
{
    tab = "";
    for (i = 0; i < dtDataForExport.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        string content = dr[i].ToString();
        content.Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, " ");
        Response.Write(tab + content);
        tab = "\t";
     }
     Response.Write("\n");
}
Response.End();
```

As you can see I have tried to a replace on `System.Environment.NewLine` but I am still getting linebreaks causing issues in the Excel Document does anyone have any suggestions to get rid of these?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe.aspx) are immutable, that means you cannot modify them, that's why this doesn't work:

```
content.Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, " ");
```

You are not reassigning the string to your variable:

```
content = content.Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, " ");
```